PageBuilder - Luma theme blocks show up as HTML only?
I've installed Magento 2.4.6 on Debian, along with the Luma theme and sample data. Most things seem to work, but PageBuilder is showing some odd behavior.
I can create and edit a new page using PageBuilder. No problem.
However, when I try to open any of the existing Luma content (for example, the Home Page Block) it displays the content only as HTML, or as an HTML block. I don't see any obvious error messages in the server logs nor in the browser console.
My expectation is that I see the existing sample Home Page Block as WYSIWIG, not HTML (as I've seen in tutorials online).
Any idea how to figure out what is going on here?



While open this, is there any error on console or log file?

@DhirenVasoya no, nothing in console or log files.

This is the default behavior of the HTML code element in the Luma theme. When you drag an HTML code element into the Page Builder, you can add your custom HTML code within it. To verify that this isn't causing any issues, you can delete the HTML code element, use other Page Builder elements to create the page, preview it, and then save the page.


Indeed, I can create elements in PB. But the sample store content provided by Magento isn't built with HTML code elements, though, is it? I have a non-technical user who would like to start with the sample store content and modify it, but the sample content doesn't open properly in PB.
